# R classification of ADM0, ADM1, ADM2 and cities into 1x1 grid

Tags: r, sf, terra

I want to work on linking temperature to socioeconomic variables.  there are wonderful databases offering 1deg x 1deg spatial resolution for temperature (such as CRU and the Berkeley BEST data base).

Many socioeconomic data exist at the political level only.  this is country, state, county, and sometimes city.  unfortunately, whoever founded the political countries and economies of our world did not do so in a regular grid.  still, some data (such as the Columbia GPW population) already exists on my grid, too.  other information does not.

What is an up-to-date (2023) method in R of obtaining the ADM0-ADM2 (country to state to county) and not just for the US but for most of the world?

Of course, I will be happy to take what I can get, which may only be ADM0 and ADM1.  (territorial would probably be better than pure map based.)  Incidentally, I have seen good solutions for how to obtain state information in the US, but I really need the world.)

Cities are probably even trickier.

Is there a data base that contains larger cities with coordinates, so that I could identify in which 1x1 cell each city lies first, for reverse mapping into my grid later?

Comment: Its not clear - do you want the vector boundary data, which you can then rasterize into a 1x1 grid, or do you want a rasterized version? A lot of small countries might have ADM2 areas smaller than that resolution though...

Comment: ideally, rasterized already.  this also means that each 1x1 cell could have multiple ADM areas --- multiple countries, states, counties, etc.

Comment: And how do you want to cope with that? Suppose bits of three countries are in a particular one degree square? What output do you want in the raster? The largest? The one that occupies the centre point of the grid?

Comment: ideally, multiple records, one for each country in a cell.  similar to https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1389495 .  (however, something akin to the largest or the most near the center would be fine, too.). right now, I am planning on trying `geodata::gadm("USA", level=2, path=".")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to create a spatial grid where each grid cell would have only one value of a specific GADM level if your aim is to match it with e.g. precipitation data efficiently.
However, reading your question and comments you seem to be interested to learn the fraction a specific grid cell is covered by either GADM1 or GADM2 level for each country in the world. The code below initiates a grid with 1°x1° resolution and iterates through country codes. It tries to load GADM2 data and where it can it delivers the fraction that grid cell is covered by the GADM2 boundaries or the national boundary where it could not.
Note that I restricted the code to run only for a single country.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.55
library(geodata)

tmp <- tempfile()
dir.create(tmp)

world <- world(path = tmp)
codes <- world$GID_0
# comment the line below if you want to run it for the whole world
codes <- "AFG"

world_grid <- rast(resolution = c(1,1))

country_stats <- lapply(codes, function(code) {
  country <- world[world$GID_0 == code, ]
  grid <- crop(world_grid, country, snap = "out")
  grid <- rasterize(country, grid, "GID_0", touches = TRUE)
  gadm2 <- gadm(code, level = 2, path = tmp)

  if(is.null(gadm2)){
    stats <- extract(grid, country, xy = TRUE, ID = TRUE, exact = TRUE, touches = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
    stats$ADM2 <- NA
  } else {
    stats <- extract(grid, gadm2, xy = TRUE, ID = TRUE, exact = TRUE, touches = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
    stats$ADM2 <- gadm2$NAME_1[stats$ID]
  }
  stats[, c("GID_0", "ADM2", "x", "y", "fraction")]
})

country_stats <- do.call(rbind, country_stats)
head(country_stats)
#>   GID_0       ADM2    x    y    fraction
#> 1   AFG Badakhshan 70.5 37.5 0.064027461
#> 2   AFG Badakhshan 71.5 37.5 0.116307607
#> 3   AFG Badakhshan 70.5 36.5 0.009188602
#> 4   AFG Badakhshan 71.5 36.5 0.114944529
#> 5   AFG Badakhshan 70.5 38.5 0.176422210
#> 6   AFG Badakhshan 71.5 38.5 0.122449366
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Warning --- I am a GIS neophyte and only marginally competent R programmer.  This should give a 1 x 1 degree grid identifying the country, state, and county closest to the center of each (integer) grid (i.e., -179.5 means -180 to -179).  In addition, it will occupy about 1GB worth of data in gadm.  Thanks to Robert H. for his help on this (offline).

It fails in not giving me multiple records for multiple administrative areas sharing the same grid; and it does not tell me the biggest cities in these grids, but it's a good start.  one could get more countries by selecting more points (e.g., in a 9x9 grid or randomly) within each degree area, of course.  there could be better solution, such as going through the records in the adm data base and attaching each area to the 1deg x 1deg, instead of what I do here, which is the opposite (going through the grid and finding what admin area is nearest the center).

```
message("thanks to UC/Davis and Robert Hijmans!")

## no one really lives farther from equator than -60 and 75...yet.

lonlatgrid <- expand.grid( lon=seq(-179.5, 179.5,1.0), lat=seq(-60.5,74.5,1.0) )

message("extracting countries at center location first")

wrldload <- geodata::world(path=".")  # install.packages("geodata")
dcountries <- terra::extract(wrldload, lonlatgrid[,1:2])  ## we will need GID0 for level-2
dcountries <- cbind( lonlatgrid, dcountries )

message("points without countries")

deeper.a <- subset( dcountries, !is.na(GID_0) )  ## we have a country

oc.by <- function (indata, INDICES, FUN, ...)
    lapply(split(1:nrow(indata), INDICES),  FUN=function(.index) FUN(indata[.index, , drop = FALSE], ...))
rbind.oc.by <- function (indata, INDICES, FUN, ...)
    as.data.frame( do.call("rbind", oc.by(indata, INDICES, FUN, ...)) )

message("pulling ADM1 and ADM2 details")

id.deeper <- function( dd ) {
                              message("Working Country ", first(dd$GID_0))
                              thiscountry <- geodata::gadm( first(dd$GID_0), level=2, path="." )
                              allcellmids <- tryCatch( terra::extract( thiscountry, cbind(dd$lon,dd$lat) ), error= function(e) NULL )
                              cbind(dd,allcellmids)
                          }

deeper.n <- rbind.oc.by( deeper.att, deeper.att$GID_0, id.deeper )


## if you also want countries that have no further ADM divisions, merge back, like
## dcountries <- merge( dcountries, deeper.n, all=T, by=c("lon", "lat") )
```